# Let current thread finish using the function before letting other threads call it C#

Tags: c#, multithreading

I can't seem to get `thread.Join()` to work for this example. I am unsure how to apply the online examples into my own code. Here's an example of my code:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

public class Example
{
    static Thread thread1, thread2, thread3, thread4;

    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Starting thread1");
        thread1 = new Thread(ThreadProc);
        thread1.Name = "Thread1";
        thread1.Start();

        Console.WriteLine("Starting thread2");
        thread2 = new Thread(ThreadProc2);
        thread2.Name = "Thread2";
        thread2.Start();

        Console.WriteLine("Starting thread3");
        thread3 = new Thread(ThreadProc3);
        thread3.Name = "Thread3";
        thread3.Start();

        Console.WriteLine("Starting thread4");
        thread4 = new Thread(ThreadProc4);
        thread4.Name = "Thread4";
        thread4.Start();

    }

    private static void ThreadProc()
    {
        //do work and creates textfile1 to store results
        sharedMethod();
        //do work until thread finishes
    }
    private static void ThreadProc2()
    {
        //do work and creates textfile2 to store results
        sharedMethod();
        //do work until thread finishes
    }
    private static void ThreadProc3()
    {
        //do work and creates textfile3 to store results
        sharedMethod();
        //do work until thread finishes
    }
    private static void ThreadProc4()
    {
        //do work and creates textfile4 to store results
        sharedMethod();
        //do work until thread finishes
    }

    private static void sharedMethod()
    {
        //wait the current thread to finish before allowing next thread to use
        //reads and prints the correct textfile for each thread to my printer
    }
}
```

I have 4 threads here that are using ThreadProc as their main functions. These main functions will then call a shared function that will print my results with my printer here. The problem appears that the printer is still busy receiving data/printing results from the previous thread but the new current thread comes in pre-maturely and causes the printer to not print the next results. Any help?

Comment: Recently I have seen some cases of people struggling with code similar to that one. And the fact that you ask how to use `Thread.Join` while it does not seem to be the right tool for the job suggest that there is somebody teaching threading with awful examples. I will keep referring people to [Threading in C#](http://www.albahari.com/threading/), if you find it useful - and I am right that there is some awful course out there - I would like to encourage you to share it too.

Comment: This will give you an idea: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/lock-statement

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It sounds like you just want a lock, using a static field for an object whose monitor you lock on:

```
private static readonly object lockForSharedMethod = new object();
...
private static void SharedMethod()
{
    lock(lockForSharedMethod)
    {
        // Code in here will only execute in a single thread
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you insist in solving this using `Thread.Join`, you would do it as follows:

```
Console.WriteLine("Starting thread1");
thread1 = new Thread(ThreadProc);
thread1.Name = "Thread1";
thread1.Start();
thread1.Join();
```

And so on for the other threads. Although doing this defies the purpose of using threads.

If you want to prevent multiple threads to enter `sharedMethod` at the same time, use [`lock`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/lock-statement).

I would like to refer you to [Threading in C#](http://www.albahari.com/threading/) for all the old school threading fundamentals in C#.